# Skew zonal polynomials, skew zonal spherical functions, and combinatorics

Tags: co.combinatorics, rt.representation-theory, symmetric-functions

Zonal polynomials may be expressed in terms of power sums as $$Z_\lambda=n!\sum_\nu \frac{1}{z_\nu }2^{n-\ell(\nu)}\omega_\lambda(\nu)p_\nu,$$ with usual notation in which $\omega_\lambda(\nu)$ are the zonal spherical functions. *Skew* zonal polynomials are defined in terms of the usual scalar product of symmetric functions by $ \langle Z_\mu Z_\nu,Z_\lambda\rangle=\langle Z_\nu,Z_{\lambda\backslash\mu}\rangle$, and we could define *skew zonal spherical functions* by the relation $$Z_{\lambda\backslash\mu}=n!\sum_\nu \frac{1}{z_\nu }2^{n-\ell(\nu)}\omega_{\lambda\backslash\mu}(\nu)p_\nu.$$

My question is whether there is a combinatorial recipe for computing $\omega_{\lambda\backslash\mu}(\nu)$ [such a recipe does exist for skew characters of the symmetric group]. I haven't found this in MacDonald's book or Stanley's paper on Jack polynomials, for instance.

EDIT: The sources I mentioned do not discuss a combinatorial interpretation of non-skew functions $\omega_\lambda(\mu)$. This is briefly discussed in Harmonic Analysis on Finite Groups (by Silberstein, Scarabotti and Tolli), but without mention of the skew case.

Comment: Is there a combinatorial model for the non-skew Zonal characters?